# Ошибка получения сервисов bleak

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, asyncio, bluetooth-le

Предназначение программы - подключение к ble-устройству и получение его сервисов, а далее и характеристик. Используется библиотека bleak,  полный код ниже

```py
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner, BleakClient
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from functools import partial


class TestApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x = [1, 6, 4]

    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal', padding=22)
        self.btn_amp = Button(text='Поиск устройств', pos_hint={'x': .23, 'y': .2}, font_size=15,
                              size_hint=(0.4, 0.4), on_press=self.show_bluetooth_devices)
        layout.add_widget(self.btn_amp)
        return layout

    def show_bluetooth_devices(self, instance):
        bl_popup = LowBluetoothPopup(size_hint=(None, None), size=(300, 400), auto_dismiss=False)
        bl_popup.open()


class LowBluetoothPopup(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LowBluetoothPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.devices = []
        self.title = "Выберите Bluetooth устройство"
        self.selected_amp_name = None
        self.selected_device = None
        self.channels = 4
        self.err = False
        self.device_type = 'amp'
        self.selected_amp_addr = None

        layout0 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', spacing=10)
        self.layout1_1 = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', spacing=10)

        asyncio.run(self.create_btns())

        layout0.add_widget(self.layout1_1)
        layout1_2 = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal', spacing=10)

        connect_btn = Button(text='Подключить', size_hint=(1, None), height='40dp')
        connect_btn.bind(on_release=self.connect_device)
        layout1_2.add_widget(connect_btn)

        refresh_btn = Button(text='Обновить', size_hint=(1, None), height='40dp')
        refresh_btn.bind(on_release=self.refresh_devices)
        layout1_2.add_widget(refresh_btn)
        layout0.add_widget(layout1_2)
        self.content = layout0

    async def create_btns(self):
        scanner = BleakScanner()
        await scanner.start()
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await scanner.stop()
        self.devices = scanner.discovered_devices
        for device in self.devices:
            if device.name:
                btn = Button(text=str(device.name), size_hint=(1, None), height='40dp')
                btn.bind(on_release=partial(self.select_device, name=device.name, addr=device.address))
                self.layout1_1.add_widget(btn)

    def select_device(self, instance, name, addr):
        for device_btn in self.layout1_1.children:
            if device_btn.__class__.__name__ == 'Button':
                device_btn.background_color = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        instance.background_color = (0, 1, 0, 1)
        self.selected_amp_name = name
        self.selected_amp_addr = addr
        print(self.selected_amp_name, self.selected_amp_addr)

    def connect_device(self, instance):
        asyncio.run(self.connect_device_as1())

    async def connect_device_as1(self):
        self.selected_device = self.selected_amp_addr
        if self.selected_device is not None:
            try:
                print(f'Подключение к {self.selected_amp_name}...')
                async with BleakClient(self.selected_device) as client:
                    services = await client.get_services()
                    for service in services:
                        print(service)
                    print(f'Подключено к {self.selected_amp_name}')
            except:
                print('Подключение не установлено')

    def refresh_devices(self, instance):
        self.layout1_1.clear_widgets()
        asyncio.run(self.create_btns())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

ОС Windows 11, версия python 3.11, bleak 0.20.2
На другом устройстве тот же самый код запускался без проблем и выдавал результат в виде списка сервисов. Здесь же, приложение зависает, ble-устройство подключается и переходит в режим ожидания запросов, а в консоли следующее:

```
[DEBUG  ] [Using proactor] IocpProactor
[DEBUG  ] Received 84:BA:20:CB:8A:54: NB2-EEG16-1054.
[DEBUG  ] Received 84:BA:20:CB:8A:54: .
[DEBUG  ] Received 84:BA:20:CB:8A:54: NB2-EEG16-1054.
[DEBUG  ] Received 84:BA:20:CB:8A:54: .
[DEBUG  ] Received 84:BA:20:CB:8A:54: NB2-EEG16-1054.
[DEBUG  ] Received E3:2E:D1:5F:67:0E: RK-G211S.
[DEBUG  ] Received E3:2E:D1:5F:67:0E: RK-G211S.
[DEBUG  ] Received E3:2E:D1:5F:67:0E: .
[DEBUG  ] Received 25:36:81:B4:C2:96: .
[DEBUG  ] Received 84:BA:20:CB:8A:54: NB2-EEG16-1054.
[DEBUG  ] [3 devices found. Watcher status] <BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStatus.STOPPED: 3>.
NB2-EEG16-1054 84:BA:20:CB:8A:54
[DEBUG  ] [Using proactor] IocpProactor
Подключение к NB2-EEG16-1054...
[DEBUG  ] Received E3:2E:D1:5F:67:0E: RK-G211S.
[DEBUG  ] Received 84:BA:20:CB:8A:54: NB2-EEG16-1054.
[DEBUG  ] Received 84:BA:20:CB:8A:54: .
[DEBUG  ] [2 devices found. Watcher status] <BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStatus.STOPPED: 3>.
[DEBUG  ] Connecting to BLE device @ 84:BA:20:CB:8A:54
[DEBUG  ] getting services (service_cache_mode=None, cache_mode=None)...
[DEBUG  ] [max_pdu_size_changed_handler] 247
[DEBUG  ] [session_status_changed_event_handler] id: BluetoothLE#BluetoothLE80:30:49:e4:f5:e0-84:ba:20:cb:8a:54, error: <BluetoothError.SUCCESS: 0>, status: <GattSessionStatus.ACTIVE: 1>
[DEBUG  ] [84:BA:20:CB:8A:54          ] services changed
[DEBUG  ] [84:BA:20:CB:8A:54          ] services changed
```

Насколько я понимаю, ключевая строка здесь `[DEBUG  ] [session_status_changed_event_handler] id: BluetoothLE#BluetoothLE80:30:49:e4:f5:e0-84:ba:20:cb:8a:54, error: <BluetoothError.SUCCESS: 0>, status: <GattSessionStatus.ACTIVE: 1>`.
Подскажите, с чем может быть связана такая беда и есть ли возможность её исправить.
Заранее спасибо за ответы.